# OpenGraph tags and HTML5 validity

Tags: facebook, html5, validation, facebook-graph

I have a HTML5 based page, and I inculded the OpenGraph tags according to it's [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/objects/builtin/). Also I checked with [Facebook Debug](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug), and it can parse the metadata.
But when I use W3C Validator, it reports the OG tags as error:

`Attribute content not allowed on element meta at this point.`
`<meta property="fb:admins" content="...." />`

`Attribute content not allowed on element meta at this point.`
`<meta property="og:url" content="http://www....">`

They are all in the `<head>`.
I would need my page be "valid" HTML5 and OG tags, as well. Could you help me giving a hint how can it be achieved?

**UPDATE:**
The `name` version *also invalid:* `<meta name='fb:admins' content=''>`

Comment: Ain't facebook using RDFa on opengraph etc tags?
With html5 it's under development http://dev.w3.org/html5/rdfa/rdfa-module.html

Answer (score 3):

Ultimately this type of metadata is **never** going to be part of the W3C spec and is therfore never going to be seen as valid by any validation engine.

I've used `name` instead of `property` before. Facebook's validator throws a warning but still parses the data and the page then passes a w3c validation.

Comment: I got errors for the `name` version, as well: `Bad value fb:admins for attribute name on element meta: Keyword fb:admins is not registered.`

Comment: @netmano can you post a link or post a js fiddle of the code?